# Select MSSQL records within X miles based on Lat/Lon in table

Tags: php, sql-server, latitude-longitude

I need a bit of help, I've tried several examples out there and i'm not able to get any of them to work.

I have a table with Name,Lat,Lon in it, i have a search page that allows a user to select within how many "miles" they would like to show other users who are in the database based on this users specific Lat/Lon, so i need a SQL statement that will return results within say 2500 miles based solely on Lat/Lon.

The key here is my database is MSSQL not MySQL and i haven't been able to get any of the MySQL examples to cross over to MSSQL. I don't think it matters but i'm use PHP on the server side to collect form data and post to MSSQL and returning a result from a function.

**Inputs:**
Lat(26.631903), Lon(-80.133376), Distance(2500)

**DB DATA:**
Name column William,
Latitude column 32.7827000,
Longitude column -96.7758000

**Output:**
Name, Distance from input Lat/Lon in miles

Comment: It's a fairly complicated process, but can be done, have a look at this link (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2690/calculate-the-geographical-distance-between-two-cities-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out, this does seem to work and isn't terribly slow

```
    //users latitude
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];

    //users longitude
    $lon = $_POST['lon'];

    //search distance
    $rad = $_POST['distance'];

    //earth radius in miles use 6371 for km
    $earth = 3959;

    $SqlStr = "
        SELECT Name, (".$earth." * ACOS(SIN(".$lat."/ CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4)))*SIN(lat / CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4)))+COS(".$lat."/ CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4)))*
        COS(lat / CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4)))*COS(lon / CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4)) - CAST(".$lon." AS NUMERIC(10,4)) / CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4))))) as distance
        FROM DB TABLE NAME
        WHERE (".$earth." * ACOS(SIN(".$lat."/ CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4)))*SIN(lat / CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4)))+COS(".$lat."/ CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4)))*COS(lat / CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4)))*
        COS(lon / CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4)) - CAST(".$lon." AS NUMERIC(10,4)) / CAST(57.2958 AS NUMERIC(10,4))))) <= ".$rad." ORDER BY distance
    ";
```